# Error Facturación Electrónica DIAN Fase 2

Tags: php, c#, xml, soap

estoy remitiendo información a la DIAN para la fase 2 de Facturación Electrónica con la URL que muestra el sitio de habilitación: https://vpfe-hab.dian.gov.co/WcfDianCustomerServices.svc?wsdl

También intenté con este otro que conseguí: 
https://gtpa-webservices-input-test.azurewebsites.net/WcfDianCustomerServices.svc?wsdl

En ambas URL todo lo que proceso me saca este error:

> An error occurred when verifying security for the message

Agradezco los que ya han pasado por este error cualquier aporte que puedan realizar.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Saludos, ¿tienes documentación de donde te puedas guiar?

Comment: La DIAN modificó el modelo de autenticación, a WS-Security 1.0 con autenticación X.509, tienen un ejemplo de como confiurarlo en SOAP UI en el anexo técnico, no se si te sirva de algo pero puedes encontrar una descripción de la configuración en SOAP UI en este link en la página 570 https://www.dian.gov.co/fizcalizacioncontrol/herramienconsulta/FacturaElectronica/InformacionTecnica/Documents/Anexos%20t%C3%A9cnicos%20Resoluci%C3%B3n%20000001.pdf , desafortunamente también estoy buscando una solución para este problema.

Comment: La ultima especificación del manual se refiere a TLS 1.2, tuve el mismo problema, pero se solucionó por lo menos en "SOAP UI" Marcando en el request la opción ``Add Default WSA: To``. "To" se creó al agregar signature en la sección ``Outgoing WS-Security Configurations``

Answer (score 2):

En SOAPUI intenté poner otra autorización además de Basic, la NTLM y en la Basic poner "Authenticate pre-emptively" la DIAN respondió. Lo que pasa es que no siempre devuelve una Response: a veces se queda pensando como colgado.

Esta es la Response al SendBillAsync:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
  <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://wcf.dian.colombia/IWcfDianCustomerServices/SendBillAsyncResponse</a:Action>
  <a:RelatesTo>uuid:127549c6-ca2b-4b83-9e70-c97ced814653</a:RelatesTo>
  <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2019-07-16T18:24:37.337Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2019-07-16T18:29:37.337Z</u:Expires>
     </u:Timestamp>
  </o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
  <SendBillAsyncResponse xmlns="http://wcf.dian.colombia">
     <SendBillAsyncResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UploadDocumentResponse" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <b:ErrorMessageList xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XmlParamsResponseTrackId">
           <c:XmlParamsResponseTrackId>
              <c:DocumentKey i:nil="true"/>
              <c:ProcessedMessage>Error descomprimiendo el archivo ZIP: El archivo está corrupto..</c:ProcessedMessage>
              <c:SenderCode i:nil="true"/>
              <c:Success>false</c:Success>
              <c:XmlFileName>ws_fdv09010987090000000001.zip</c:XmlFileName>
           </c:XmlParamsResponseTrackId>
        </b:ErrorMessageList>
        <b:ZipKey/>
     </SendBillAsyncResult>
  </SendBillAsyncResponse>
</s:Body>
```

Comment: Esta es una respuesta a la pregunta?